# Haskell - Strange do block behavior

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, do-notation

While reading the **Haskell Wikibook** about [MonadPlus](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/MonadPlus), I found the following function which basically takes a `Char` and a `String` and returns `Just (char,tail)` if such char is equal the string head, or `Nothing` otherwise:

```
char :: Char -> String -> Maybe (Char, String)
char c s = do
  let (c':s') = s
  if c == c' then Just (c, s') else Nothing
```

and they explain that `let (c':s') = s` will not produce an exception, cause it is in a `do` block which would evaluate to `Nothing` when the pattern fails, but, that isn't the case, because when I tried it:

```
*Main> char 'a' ""
*** Exception: exercice2.hs:5:7-17: Irrefutable pattern failed for pattern (c' : s')
```

So I had to rewrite it to:

```
char' :: Char -> String -> Maybe (Char, String)
char' _ [] = Nothing
char' c (c':s') 
  | c == c' = Just (c,s')
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

and it worked as expected... Why is it happening to me?

Comment: Off topic: [1] Nitpicking: Haskell Wiki /= Haskell Wikibook (it is a common mix-up). [2] If there is indeed a bug in the book it was a very appropriate moment to report it, as the MonadPlus chapter will be updated for the AMP in a short while. Thanks!

Comment: @duplode Ok, I am going to change it to Haskell Wikibook as you said

Comment: @duplode Sorry for my ignorance, but what does AMP mean?

Comment: @FtheBuilder [Applicative-Monad Proposal](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal)

Comment: Applicative-Monad Proposal, that is, the changes in GHC 7.10 that made `Applicative` a superclass of `Monad`. To pick an arbitrary example, `guard`, which used to have a `MonadPlus` constraint, now has an `Alternative` one. That means there is some slightly broken code in the Monad Transformers chapter of the book (which uses `guard` in one example), and fixing it in the proper way will require discussing `Alternative` in the MonadPlus chapter.

Comment: (By the way, I have just fixed the code in the book.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the wiki is wrong. They are probably confusing this with the fact that *binds* fail via the [`fail`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:fail) function a `Monad` affords. So the following example *will* use the `fail` function from `Maybe`, which returns `Nothing`:

```
char :: Char -> String -> Maybe (Char, String)
char c s = do
  (c':s') <- return s
  if c == c' then Just (c, s') else Nothing
```

Comment: Yup, it is wrong indeed. Most likely the author of the exercise mistyped `let` instead of `<-`, and in the intervening eight years it slipped through the fingers of everyone (myself included!).